# How to change the navigationController's rootViewController

Tags: objective-c

In the appDelegate,I create a A_NavigationController to become self.window.rootViewController,and set a X_ViewController to become the rootViewController, after an other viewController pushed,I create a new B_NavigationController ,seted a new Y_ViewController to become the rootViewController and used presentModalViewController method ,added the B_NavigationeController. Now I want to do is,when I dismissed the Y_ViewController can change the A_NavigationController's rootViewController.

```
     self.viewController = [[AViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.navCon=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.navCon;


  BViewController *bView=[[BViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"BViewController" bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController *navCon=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:bView];
        [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navCon animated:YES];

//in BViewController.m
//I want a method to change the window's rootViewController.
```

Comment: You asked it 2 days ago, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10154765/change-the-rootviewcontroller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "rootViewController" is only the UIViewController on the bottom of the navigationStack. To change it you can just set the object at index 0 to whatever controller you want